# window.location.pathname redirects to double host name

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `url = '/Pria/Sepatu'`

and a select box with options:

```
<option value="' + url +'">'+ list[i].category +'</option>');
```

and the following javascript:

```
window.location.pathname = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

however this always redirects me to `mysite.com/mysite.com/Pria/Sepatu` instead of

```
mysite.com/Pria/Sepatu
```

Why is this?

Comment: `document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: Does simply `window.location` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case:

```
location.assign(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

if your top url is: `http://www.mysite.com`
and if `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value is "Pria/Sepatu"`

then just do it like this:

```
location.assign(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

Comment: and url is relative url as what I have above?

Comment: @adit Edited answer please check

Comment: It will work to change last value of the url like "Sepatu"  can be changed to "Septu2". Then try only `location.href="$WHOLE_URL$`.